# Visual Studio 2010 won't build the project

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

I have the Visual Studio 2010 premium installed (iam a student and I have the vs2010 installed from our msdnaa).  I wrote a small windows form application.

When I try to compile and run the program using <kbd>F5</kbd>, the green start button turns off for 3-5 seconds, then I get an error :

> The file "obj\x86\Debug\Test.exe" cannot be copied into "bin\Debug\Test.exe".

The process cannot access the file "bin\debug\Test.exe", because it is used from other process. (Please note that I translated the error message from German)

To solve this problem, I do have to go to the debug folder and delete the Test.exe file, then recompile the Program (hitting F5) but this won`t start the debugging,I do have to start the program from Test.exe from the bin\Debug folder.

How can I solve this problem?

It is annoying then I don't have any chance to debug anymore, and also it takes too much time to delete the file, then start it again after building it.

Please help, I did tried to reinstall the VS2010 again, but this didn't help.

Comment: Are you using source control?

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus running?

Comment: Should this be migrated to Stack Overflow as it is a programming issue, or leave it here because it is an application issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your usually get this type of error message from VS 2010 when your application hangs or is still executing and you didn't close it. 
I recommend trying the following variants:

- 1) make a new empty project and try to see if you have the same F5 problem. If yes proceed to the next point, if no then your application is hanging
- 2) try saving the project file in a different location (on a diferent drive or a diferent folder). Or
- 3) check if VS2010 has **DELETE** rights on that path, if not, add that right and then you should have no souch problem

Hope that helps,
IPP

Comment: +1 for the delete rights, did not think of getting down at that level (besides the file having a lock by a background running thread...)

Answer (score 0):

First I would install SP1 for Visual Studio if you have not done so already.

Either use the [Web Based Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691) or the [Full ISO Download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710) to install.

If the problem still exists, you may want to see if starting Visual Studio with any add-ins disabled and see if that fixes the issue and narrows down the culprit.

Update #1: Ensure your application is not running and you have no background threads still executing (thus causing the file to be locked)